# Estado "stuck" y "Pending" al lanzar un job en GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, jobs

Estoy probando de lanzar un job muy sencillo y no  encuentro la manera de que funcione, y tampoco entiendo porqué falla. Por ahora he hecho un commit y un push en el fichero .gitlab-ci.yml tal como dice la documentación con el simple código para imprimir en el bash un "Hellow world". Gitlab se queda permamentemente en estado "stuck" y "pending".

Incluyo el código del fichero .gitlab-ci.yml

File .gitlab-ci.yml on project

```
    before_script:
  - bash echo 'hellow world'


stages:
    - test

job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bash echo 'hellow world'

  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - testPrimerJob
```

Finalmente después de vuestra ayuda me he dado cuenta que me faltaba un "runner" para poder lanzar el job. Y lo he creado usando la documentación y los pasos de gitlab.

Para crear el runner:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html

Para registrar el runner:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/

Aun así no he conseguido que me funcione, nada más entrar en gitlab ya aparece el runner como "locked" en el panel de admin/runners (parece ser una issue de la versión 10.3.0). Igualmente he probado a vincularlo al proyecto y lanzar el job sencillo que he puesto anteriormente. El resultado es el mismo, "pending indefinido".

Como dato pondré que al escoger que tipo de "runner" he escogido "shell" que entiendo es el que mejor me iba para esta prueba, si estoy equivocado me corregís.

Me encontrado también un error al instalar el "runner", y era por un tema que nuestro servidor que se encarga de resolver dominios, por algun problema no podría. El error es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mañana abriré otra pregunta para no ensuciar esta.

Comment: no tienes ninguna salida de log de la ejecución de gitlab? llegas a ver los `echo` ??

Comment: No, gitlab se queda en puntos suspensivos y no llega a imprimir nada, ni bien ni mal, es que parece más un problema de configuración o que falte algo para instalar, no puedo ver ningun echo

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como aparece en [la documentación](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/README.html#sh-bash-shells), parece ser diferente:

```
# This command is used if the build should be executed in context
# of another user (the shell executor)
cat generated-bash-script | su --shell /bin/bash --login user

# This command is used if the build should be executed using
# the current user, but in a login environment
cat generated-bash-script | /bin/bash --login

# This command is used if the build should be executed in
# a Docker environment
cat generated-bash-script | /bin/bash
```

> Por tanto, para tu ejemplo, entiendo que debería ser:
>
> `echo "echo 'hola'" | /bin/bash --login`

**EDICIÓN**

Comenta la pregunta original, que esto es lo que observa [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, parece que no hay un runner activo.

Adjunto pantalla de la pinta que debería tener el runner:

[image: Pantalla de Runners en Gitlab]

Comment: Pero crees que el problema puede ser este? voy a probarlo y comento que tal ha ido. Tenia la duda de que fuera algo de configuarión o que tenga que ver con los runners.

Pruebo y comento, gracias

Comment: claro, echa un vistazo no sea que sólo llamas a la Shell pero no hace nada. Si no, deberías poder ver con `ps -efa` si se queda el comando pillado...

Comment: este comando en una linea aparte o seguido del comando --login... He estado probando "echo este comando "echo 'hola'" | /bin/bash --login" y se queda pillada la consola de igual manera, puede que me falte algo? instalar un runner o no tiene nada que ver? gracias

Comment: ummm, es decir, que se te queda pillada la shell aún lanzándolo desde fuera? `"echo 'hola'" | /bin/bash --login" `

Comment: Dejo una imagen al ver el job lo que se aprecia. https://ibb.co/dCMW7G

Comment: Si Alejandro , yo lo que hago es añadir el código en el gitlab-ci.yml luego he hecho el commit y push. Voy a la pestaña CI CD de gitlab y compruebo que tal va el job, y me encuentro lo de la imagen.

Comment: ok, luego eso parece ser que no tienes un runner asociado. Ve a la pestaña de Admin de gitlab, Overview, Runners. Mira que tengas un runner compartido, asócialo a tu proyecto, y prueba de nuevo

Comment: Acabo de ir a la pestaña runners, en el menu admin de gitlab y aparece esto, no hay runner disponible. https://ibb.co/gmt8Mb. Es normal o necesito seguro un runner? gracias de antemano

Comment: Sí, necesitas un runner por obligación. Te pego en la respuesta cómo lo tengo yo configurado.

Comment: Gracias voy a instalar un "runner" y a ver si puedo conseguir que funcione, de mucha ayuda Alejandro!

Comment: Encantado!! Cuéntanos qué has conseguido, para dejar la pregunta/respuesta documentada!!!

Comment: por cierto, https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html echa un ojo aquí que están bastante automatizadas las instalaciones!!